# Keyboard characters in different locales

Tags: android, keyboard, locale, ime

I'm developing a keyboard (IME) for Android. I want it to be useful for people from every country. So, I need to know which symbols should be placed on keyboard based on current locale.

My first idea is to copy computer keyboard layouts. Where can I get the contents of preferred computer keyboard layout for each locale?

Also, I've noticed that phone keyboards usually contains some special symbols which aren't present on computer keyboard. Which symbols are important for phones and why? For example, all keyboards I've met provide a way to type '¿' symbol. But this symbol doesn't make any sense in my locale (russian) and isn't used in english. Is there a reason for placing this symbol on every keyboard?

Comment: Seems to me, that keys layouts are hardcoded into IME programs. Beause all such programs (in Windows at least) are slightly different with layouts. However, in Windows you may use some functions to determine available characters for HKL, for example `GetKeyNameText`, `MapVirtualKeyEx` and so on. My be android has similar functions?